# QT/QML:How to show a message when the model has no data

Tags: qt, listview, model, qml

I've implement a simple Model View app, when there is no data in the model, the ListView is just a blank form. I want to know how to show a convenient message,telling that the model has no data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Overlay a listview and a text element on top of each other. Set visibilty to true or false depending on model.count

```
ListView{
     visible : if(model.count > 0) true;else false;
}
Text{
     visible : if(model.count > 0) false;else true;
}
```

Comment: Hi,I get this error:QDeclarativeExpression: Expression "(function $visible() { return listView.model.count >0 ? false:true })" depends on non-NOTIFYable properties:  QDeclarativeFolderListModel::count, and it does not work

Comment: Then you can either fix QDeclarativeFolderListModel to have a NOTIFY signal for its count property, or try using listView.count, which is NOTIFYable.

Answer (score 1):

At least with QtQuick2 you can do something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ListView {
    model: ...
    clip: true

    Label {
        anchors.fill: parent
        horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
        visible: parent.count == 0
        text: qsTr("Nothing to show yet!")
        font.bold: true
    }
}
```